# how to read a bean object existing on the server using proxy object in java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

i have 2 machines say A and B. I have a bean object BO at machine A. I want to create a proxy object at B and read the data of BO and store it in a file in machine B.
I have used sockets to connect A and B.
Its my first question on stack overflow. Please ask if anyone needs any clarification.

The code for the bean class is as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FileBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private ArrayList<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private int var2;

   public ArrayList<Integer> getVar1() {
       return var1;
   }

   public void setVar1(ArrayList<Integer> var1) {
       this.var1 = var1;
   }

   public int getVar2() {
       return var2;
   }

   public void setVar2(int var2) {
       this.var2 = var2;
   }


   public boolean equals(Object o) {        
       if (this == o) return true;        

       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;  

       FileBean fb = (FileBean) o;           

       if (var2 != fb.getVar2()) 
          return false; 

       if (var1 != null ? !var1.equals(fb.var1) : var1 != null) 
          return false; 

       return true;         
   } 

   public String toString() 
   {       
       return "Var1 = " + this.getVar1() + " ; Var2 = " + this.getVar2();  
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to show us some code which you found problematic.

Comment: i hve never used a proxy object before today and quite confused with the samples provided online. Can you just provide me the steps to create a proxy object ??

Comment: There is no way we can explain it unless we understand your question. What have you tried? Show us the code

Comment: I have added the code for the bean class. I have a created a object of it on machine B and want to tranfer it and store it contents on machine A. Machine A doesnt have this FileBean class. Over the net i found that it could be done using proxy object.